# Azure Stream Analytics has function like GETDATE() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP？

Tags: azure, stream, timestamp, analytics, getdate

My scenarios is that sensors always store data at local,sometime these data will be uploaded to Event Hub but I don't need all the data,I need filter data by a time field in Azure Stream Analytics. But Azure Stream does not have GETDATE() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Is there any other alternatives ?

```
SELECT
  devId,
  dataType,
  utc
INTO
  into
FROM
  output
WHERE
 (TRY_CAST(utc AS bigint) IS NOT NULL) AND
 (DATEADD(millisecond, utc, '1970/01/01 GMT') >= DATEADD(minute,-5,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **System.Timestamp** like here and also filter/group by for a given time window:

SELECT
    *
INTO
    ArchiveOutput
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP BY Time

SELECT
    Make,
    **System.TimeStamp** AS Time,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
INTO
    AlertOutput
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP BY Time
GROUP BY
    Make,
    TumblingWindow(second, 10)
HAVING
    [Count] >= 3

You have many other examples here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns/#query-example-find-last-event-in-a-window

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Can some detail for my scenario.